# The economy of trapping

Tags: chess, optimization

A queen on the center of the board has 27 possible moves. Sometimes a queen can be trapped, like in the position below.

[image]

Note: This is just an example of a what a trap should be like-every possible square is covered. This is not meant to conform to all of my rules.

If a queen is on a central square, what is the least number of points needed to trap it?

Rules:

1. No kings are allowed.
2. Queens are worth nine points, rooks are worth 5 points, bishops and knights are worth 3 points, and pawns are worth 1 point.
3. You are allowed an unlimited supply of pieces.
4. A queen is trapped if it can immediately be captured on whatever square it can move to. If it can capture an enemy piece, that piece must be protected. The queen is still trapped even if a piece that can be captured is a queen, so long as it is protected.
5. The trapped queen must have full access to it potential range on a central square.

Comment: You could improve **Rule 5**: "The queen must start on field D4,D5,E4 or E5 and be able to actually move to all 27 fields in its range."

Comment: @RewanDemontay Could you please elaborate on Rule 5? I would like to take a shot at this puzzle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe I've found a solution worth 16 points.

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution which needs

> 19

points:

> [image]